# In node.js, when I try to reference an array in a json file, it returns undefined

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

So I'm editing code right now, and I'm making a system that reads an array in a JSON file, and determines what to do *if* a user's id is in the array.

So, I put `const idarray = require('./config.json').idarray
         if (idarray.includes("1234")) return console.log(idarray);`

So, it should return the contents of the array, right? Well no, it doesn't. It returns 'undefined', and crashes. Could I get some help? I've used this multiple times before, and it hasn't errored once...

Comment: I'd also like to note that the array includes "1234", so you can eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Doesn't seem a little impossible that anyone could help without actually seeing the JSON file? A question like this needs a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: JSON file: `{
   "idarray": ["1234"]
}`

Comment: I guess no answer?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. `idarray.includes("1234")` works find with that input for me.

Comment: Oh... I wonder why, it might just be an error on Node's end..

Comment: Do you get an expected result when you just `console.log(idarray)`?

Comment: Do you at least **export** this array in your `config.json`? Note that a `require` is not made for `json` files but for `js` files...